# Сверточные нейронные сети, Матрица ядра свертки

Tags: нейронные-сети

Здравствуйте! В самом первом этапе когда на вход мы получаем исходную картинку (например фотография буквы), требуется пройтись по ней окном n*n размера и умножения на ядро (матрицу свертки), для построения карт признаков (Feature Maps). Но нигде не написано какие значения должны быть в самом ядре (матрице свертки, то есть на какие значения надо умножать матрицу), можно ли будет использовать эту матрицу как ядро свертки для определения краев?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же если размер входной картинки 30*30, то можно ли будет проходиться по ней окном 5*5, этого достаточно для достижения оптимальной точности распознавания?

На какое ядро свертки лучше всего умножать участок входной картинки для наибольшей точности распознавания? Или изначально все значения в матрице ядра равны нулям? Можно ли еще спросить, по какому правилу или формуле определяется количество карт признаков? Или если задача стоит в распознавании 26 букв Английского алфавита, то в каждом этапе построения карт признаков их должно быть ровно 26? Заранее Вам спасибо!

Comment: Может [эта](http://www.dspguide.com/ch26/4.htm) информация чем-то поможет. Есть перевод на русский: [Смит. Цифровая обработка сигналов](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/knigi-izdatelstva-dodeka/shemotehnika/978-5-94120-145-7/).

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос! Убираю мой "мусор". Начинаю разбираться :-) http://eblearn.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Сначала заполняй случайными значениями, а в процессе обучения корректируешь значения

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?